# Have a list from a sub list of objects

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have two classes (Entity Framework, code first) like these:

```
public class Order
{
    [Id and other properties]
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Id and other properties]
    public String ItemCode { get; set; }
}
```

what I want is the list of orders that contain a specific ItemCode (like ItemCode == "pasta")

TIA

Comment: could you please share your attempted code ?

Comment: The problem is I don't find how to start. I mean, I can have the list of Items, like this


var mItems = db.Items.Select(i => i.ItemCode == "pasta");

And of course I can have the list adding .ToList()
But after that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zeta: you were near there

The right solution is :

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
[populate orders list]

var myList = orders.Where(o => o.Items.Any(i => i.ItemCode == "pasta")).ToList();
```

(You forgot the "Items" before Any)
Thank you so much

Comment: I saw it a bit later after I posted it and edited it ^^ but no problem